# read csv in for loops and move to the next one python

Tags: python, for-loop

Sorry for being not so clear. I want to read csv files in a for loop. each file is afterwards processed with some calculations. Afterwards I want to read the next file and do the same. Instead of manually changing the file names how can I do this with a loop ?
My code below is not working, putting the filenames for the pd_read_csv is wrong. But how to solve this?

```
filenumber=0
for files in range(4):
    filenames=["file1","file2",
               "file3","file4"]

    os.chdir(r"/folder")

    results=pd.read_csv('files[filenumber].csv',sep=',',header=0, index_col=None)

#dosomething with the file and move than to the next file
filenumber=+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
filenames=["file1","file2","file3","file4"]

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    filename = filenames[i]+'.csv'
    results=pd.read_csv(filename,sep=',',header=0, index_col=None)
    # Now do whatever operations you want
```

Since you have a pattern in your file names, another way would be:

```
for i in range(4):
    filename = 'file'+str(i+1)+'.csv'
    results=pd.read_csv(filename,sep=',',header=0, index_col=None)
    # Now do whatever operations you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your entire computer automatically:

```
import csv

import os


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".\\your_directory_to_start\\"):
# for each file and directory...
    for file in files:
        # for each file 
        if file.endsswith(".csv"):
        # if file is csv
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
             # show file name with location
             ruta_completa = os.path.join(root, file)
             # store in a variable the full path to file
             mi_archivo = open(ruta_completa)
             #open the file
             mi_csv = csv.reader(mi_archivo)
             # extract data from file
             mis_datos = list(mi_csv)
             # convert data from file into list
             mis_datos
             # show in screen all the data
             mis_datos[0]
             #extract the first row value
             mis_datos[0][0]
             #extract the first cell value in the first row 
             # do whatever you want... even create a new xlsx file or csv file
```